# MS Exchange seems altering inbound email headers - which is then failing DKIM checks

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email, exchange, dkim

I've recently been trying to implement DMARC for inbound email on our MS exchange server.
We are currently using [SpamAssassin in a Box](https://stackoverflow.com) to achieve this. Any SPF lookups seem to be working fine now, but some (not all) DKIM signature checks fail and end up in the spam inbox - I believe this is due to our Exchange server altering the DKIM signed body of the incoming mail.

Today a colleague has setup a separate VPS running Exchange server.

Just as a test, we both signed up to the same online newsletter, the newsletter email passes DKIM on his Exchange server, but seems to fail on mine.
If we compare the headers of both emails:

The last part of the headers that all-elektronics.de (Newsletter provider) sent to us (i.e. which were not added by exchange) is this Date header here, as seen from my colleague's Exchange server:
[Date header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHCyP.png)

However, if I look at the headers on the newsletter received on my Exchange Server, it seems to add additional headers below this Date header : [Added headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfAfe.jpg)

The first thing which breaks DKIM is the fact that Exchange removes an extra blank line which was sent to us in the original email, this is from my colleagues Exchange server , notice the two "LF"s meaning two blank lines: [Blank lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGpCO.jpg)

Since my Exchange server  is adding all those extra headers, it ended up removing the extra blank line when it tried to cleanup: [No blank lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFU0p.jpg)

The "body" of an email, which is calculated with DKIM, starts on the first line after the first blank line of the headers. I.e., that CRLF indicated in the above screenshot denotes the "boundary" between header and body.

But in the original email they sent, before Exchange altered it, there were two blank lines. This means that the second of those two blank lines actually counts as part of the body and is taken into account when making the calculation. Exchange removing the extra one broke it

My Exchange server also seems to be changing the capitalisation of Content-Transfer-Encoding which is also breaking DKIM

I have also setup pipeline tracing but the original.eml email fails dkim signature checks - which points to the pipeline transport agents NOT being responsible for the altered body headers.

Any help on this would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Which Exchange version and is it fully updated? Have you seen [On-Premises Exchange: DKIM and DMARC setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/technet-wiki/35595.on-premises-exchange-dkim-and-dmarc-setup)?

Comment: Exchange server 2019 + latest version.
I believe the link you have sent is for enabling dkim signing of outgoing email - my issue is that Exchange seems to be altering incoming emails.

Comment: Do you find this problem when forwarding mail?

Comment: Did you install the DKIM plugin and configure some settings to enable inbound DKIM/SPF/DMARC authentication and authentication in Exchange Server 2019. This may help you: https://dmarcian.com/dkim-dmarc-microsoft-exchange/

Comment: We already have a plugin handing OUTBOUND dkim signing - this is working fine.

for INBOUND dkim signature checking we are using Spamassassin.
As mentioned in my post, most dkim signature checks do pass - It's just that a handful are failing (when they shouldn't) and the fails are down to exchange server interfering with incoming mail headers.

It seems to mostly fail for emails that have embedded images - I think it's something to do with Transfer encoding but I am stuck.

Comment: Usually, emails are checked at arrival, so Transport Rules and such don't mess with Authentication-Results. Is Spam Assassin still a hop on inbound email? Is it possible that Spam Assassin is altering headers?

Comment: I believe that Spam Assassin does the DKIM signature check after the email has passed through the exchange transport pipeline (I must admit this is an assumption, but I'm pretty sure that's how it works)

I guess it is possible that Spam Assassin is responsible for changing some headers - but I do think it's exchange at fault - more specifically when it changes the content format of an email, but I'm struggling to prove it

Comment: The more I think about it, it can't be SpamAssassins fault.
If I enable pipeline tracing to capture an inbound email (before and after it goes through the pipeline) I can see that the original.eml fails a dkim check when checked via dkimpy (python based script that checks dkim signatures of .eml files) and all of this is BEFORE the email reaches spamassassin

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have Spam Assassin in front of your Exchange Server, to filter out SPAM, on inbound email? Where do your MX records point?

Comment: Possibly, but this instance of SpamAssassin comes from Exchange Server Toolbox:
https://www.jam-software.com/exchange_server_toolbox

Like I mentioned the spam filter part (and more specifically DMARC) works fine 90% of the time, there just seems to be some issues with a few emails.
There must be a way around this rather than moving to something else

Comment: I found some information on the SpamAssassin-in-a-box and indeed Exchange passes it to SpamAssassin for analysis, after which it is passed back with a score. So I guess you're right about Exchange receiving the emails first :) Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: No worries, It's always good to have someone second guessing - that way you need to double check what you think you already know!